# Getting 2 responses from one http request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

When I make a post request to my node.js backend using axios and I look in my chrome console network tab, I see 2 http requests to the endpoint instead of 1.

The first one has a status code of 200 and a response of GET,HEAD,POST

The second one is the one I was expecting which is a status code of 200 and whatever I set my response to be.

Is it normal to get that 1st response of GET,HEAD,POST as well or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: See preflight request: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Comment: Is the first request a CORS preflight request?

Comment: I have this code in node.js because I was having an issue running on my localhost whereby react was on port 3000 and node on port 8000 so I was having CORS issues. `app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  next();
});`

Comment: Get, head and post are *methods*, not responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you indicated that you're using different hosts (or ports at least), this is a default behaviour of browsers to check, if the CORS protocol is understood.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS):

> CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) is a system, consisting of transmitting HTTP headers, that determines whether browsers block frontend JavaScript code from accessing responses for cross-origin requests.
>
> The same-origin security policy forbids cross-origin access to resources. But CORS gives web servers the ability to say they want to opt into allowing cross-origin access to their resources.

You can find more about CORS and prefligh requests in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).